# Hidden tabs not showing correct layout

Tags: html, css, layout, tabs

i'm currently developing a page for a friend and the goal is for the sardines cans to work as a kind of menu to display some details.

Before having the tabs it was working fine as presented in the image:

[image]

after using the tabs i lost my original layout... anyone has a clue how to solve this? I'm sure my problem is in my css.

Used Code:

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Mar de Sardinhas</title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">

    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>



<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:300,300i" rel="stylesheet">



<!-- scripts de visivel / invisivel


<script type="text/javascript">

    function toggle_visibility(id) {
       var e = document.getElementById(id);
       if(e.style.display == 'block')
          e.style.display = 'none';
       else
          e.style.display = 'block';
    }

</script>

 css para styling -->


<style type="text/css">

.off {
  -webkit-filter: grayscale(100%); /* Safari 6.0 - 9.0 */
  filter: grayscale(100%);


}

.on {


}

.position{

  position: relative;
  bottom: -30%;
  transition: 0.3s;

}

.position:hover {

  position: relative;
  bottom: 0%;
  transition: 0.3s;

}


.imgsize{

  max-width: 10vw;

}


.wide-as-needed {
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  overflow: auto;
  overflow-x: scroll;
  overflow-y: hidden;
  white-space: nowrap; width:100%;
}

.fundo{


    background:rgba(255,255,255,0.5);

}

.texto {
    font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
}

.preview{ 

    max-width:100%;
    max-height:100%;

}

.tinted-image {
  background: 
    /* top, transparent red, faked with gradient */ 
    linear-gradient(
      rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.9), 
      rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.7), 
      rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.7), 
      rgba(255, 255, 255, 0)
    ),
    /* bottom, image */
    url(bg.jpeg);
}
.lata {
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
  color: white;
}

.hide {
  display:none;
}

.tab {
  overflow: hidden;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
}

.tabcontent {
  display: none;
  padding: 6px 12px;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  border-top: none;
}

</style>







</head>


<body background="bg.jpeg" class="tinted-image" style="background-attachment: fixed;">

<div class= "row tabcontent" id="London">

<!-- parte do texto episodio 1-->

<div class="col-sm-12 col-lg-4 m-4 " style="overflow-y:scroll; max-height: 65vh; position: static;">

    <div class="texto m-2">
        <h2>Origens</h2>

        <p>
A arte de conservar alimentos foi sempre uma constante na história da humanidade. Os métodos mais ancestrais como a defumação e a salga permitiram o consumo de peixe em larga escala e o seu transporte para zonas distantes do litoral. Até o século XVII, parte do pescado conservado tinha por objectivo o fornecimento de navios envolvidos na expansão Ultramarina. 
No entanto Portugal tem uma tradição milenar na conservação de pescado que remonta ao período grego e romano, com a produção do Garum – uma afamada conserva de sangue e vísceras de peixes que se deixava a secar em salmoura e que era exportada para todo o mediterrâneo.
        </p>

    </div>

    <div class="texto">

        <h2><i>Origins</i></h2>
        <p><i>
The art of preserving food has always been a constant in the history of mankind. More ancestral methods such as smoking and salting have allowed the consumption of fish on a large scale and its transport to areas far from the coast. Until the seventeenth century, part of the preserved fish had the objective of supplying ships involved in the Overseas expansion.
However Portugal has a millennial tradition in the conservation of fish that goes back to the Greek and Roman period, with the production of Garum - a famous preserve of blood and viscera of fish that was allowed to dry in brine and that was exported to all the Mediterranean.</i> </p>

    </div>
</div>

<!-- segunda coluna episodio 1-->
<div class="col m-4 ">


        <div >
        <img src="e01.png"  class="preview mt-2">
        </div>

        <div class="d-flex justify-content-center ">
        <a href="#" class="btn btn-info mt-2 texto" role="button" aria-pressed="true">Ver Filme / Watch Movie</a>
        </div>




</div>

</div>  


<div class= "row tabcontent" id="Paris">

<!-- parte do texto episodio 1-->

<div class="col-sm-12 col-lg-4 m-4 " style="overflow-y:scroll; max-height: 65vh; position: static;">

    <div class="texto m-2">
        <h2>Origens 2</h2>

        <p>
testeeee
No entanto Portugal tem uma tradição milenar na conservação de pescado que remonta ao período grego e romano, com a produção do Garum – uma afamada conserva de sangue e vísceras de peixes que se deixava a secar em salmoura e que era exportada para todo o mediterrâneo.
        </p>

    </div>

    <div class="texto">

        <h2><i>Origins</i></h2>
        <p><i>
The art of preserving food has always been a constant in the history of mankind. More ancestral methods such as smoking and salting have allowed the consumption of fish on a large scale and its transport to areas far from the coast. Until the seventeenth century, part of the preserved fish had the objective of supplying ships involved in the Overseas expansion.
However Portugal has a millennial tradition in the conservation of fish that goes back to the Greek and Roman period, with the production of Garum - a famous preserve of blood and viscera of fish that was allowed to dry in brine and that was exported to all the Mediterranean.</i> </p>

    </div>
</div>

<!-- segunda coluna episodio 1-->
<div class="col m-4 ">


        <div >
        <img src="e01.png"  class="preview mt-2">
        </div>

        <div class="d-flex justify-content-center ">
        <a href="#" class="btn btn-info mt-2 texto" role="button" aria-pressed="true">Ver Filme / Watch Movie</a>
        </div>




</div>

</div>  

<!-- barra de baixo-->


<div class="container-fluid fixed-bottom">


    <div class="row flex-row flex-nowrap ml-1 mr-2 wide-as-needed">

        <div>
            <a href="#" class="tablinks" onclick="openCity(event, 'London')">
        <img src="1.png"  class="on position imgsize">
            </a>
        </div>

        <div>
            <a href="#" class="tablinks" onclick="openCity(event, 'Paris')">
        <img src="2.png" class="off position imgsize">
        </a>
        </div>

        <div>
        <img src="3.png" class="off position imgsize">
        </div>

        <div>
        <img src="4.png"  class="on position imgsize">
        </div>

        <div>
        <img src="1.png" class="off position imgsize" >
        </div>

        <div>
        <img src="1.png" class="on position imgsize">
        </div>

        <div>
        <img src="1.png" class="on position imgsize">
        </div>

        <div>
        <img src="1.png" class="on position imgsize">
        </div>

        <div>
        <img src="1.png" class="on position imgsize">
        </div>

        <div>
        <img src="1.png" class="on position imgsize">
        </div>

    </div>
</div>
</div>


<script>
function openCity(evt, cityName) {
  var i, tabcontent, tablinks;
  tabcontent = document.getElementsByClassName("tabcontent");
  for (i = 0; i < tabcontent.length; i++) {
    tabcontent[i].style.display = "none";
  }
  tablinks = document.getElementsByClassName("tablinks");
  for (i = 0; i < tablinks.length; i++) {
    tablinks[i].className = tablinks[i].className.replace(" active", "");
  }
  document.getElementById(cityName).style.display = "block";
  evt.currentTarget.className += " active";
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

The page can be found here: [working page](http://foodcost.pt/sardines/#)

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A visible "row" class's display value should be "flex" when utilizing Bootstrap 4. In this line from your JavaScript, your "tabcontent" DIV is being overridden to display "block":

```
document.getElementById(cityName).style.display = "block";
```

Switch "block" to "flex" and you should get the behavior you're looking for.

Comment: solved! I had tried something similar in the first script i tried but with no results! thanks!